# Using an array in select expert, is it possible?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I currently have the following in select expert to select a bunch of fields:

```
{Order.OrderDate} in {?Start date} to {?End date} and
{Order.PostingCode} in ["j500", "j501", "j502"]
```

I am having to add from j500 all the way up to j713.

Is it possible to point it to a string array?

For example, in java:

```
int count = 0;
int fieldnumber = 500;
String[] fieldarray = new String[214];

    while (count  < 214){
        System.out.println("j"+fieldnumber);
        fieldarray[count] = "j"+fieldnumber;
        fieldnumber++;
        count++;
    }
```

So in crystal I could just point crystal at the "fieldarray" string array and say use everything in there. Is that possible with crystal? If so, how?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use:

```
{Order.OrderDate} in {?Start date} to {?End date} and
{Order.PostingCode} >= "j500" and
{Order.PostingCode} <= "j713"
```

Comment: Goddamn, this is what I get for over thinking something.